# How call internal method only with certain class and access those class variables

Tags: c++, methods

I'm putting together a recursive method, and need to be able to only call one method with one class type, but also access the variables of that class in the method called.  How would I do that?  I'm not sure what to search for online for this or what it's called. I realize people here don't have info on inner workings on my `OurMap`, but we can assume it's `std::map`. We are starting in `toJson`, once we're ready to convert internal data to the other format and are getting the data out of our data structure recursively. See comment below.

```
class OurNode: public OurIF
{
public:
    void OurNode::toJson()
    {
       GenericValue doc(Rapidjson::kObjectType);
       this.buildTree(doc);
    }

    void OurNode::buildTree(GenericValue &doc)
    {
        OurMetaType t == m_value.type();
        if(t == OurMapMeta)
            m_value.getMap().buildTree(doc);
        else if(t == OurListMeta)
            m_value.getList().buildTree(doc);
        else if(t == string)
            doc.AddMember(m_name, m_value);
    }

    //OurMap is a map of a string, OurValue combination
    void OurMap::buildTree(GenericValue &doc)
    {
       OurMap m = this.OurMap.getValue();  //how would I access a calling class data if not this? Technically, this is OurNode, not OurMap. How do I get the OurMap data?
    }

    private:
    string m_name;
    OurValue m_value;  //could be int, double, string, OurMap, OurList, etc
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143027/discussion-on-question-by-michele-how-call-internal-method-only-with-certain-cla).

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that @AndyG had in the comment that was moved to chat:

I think what you're trying to say is that OurMap is the caller of OurNode::buildTree, and you want to access a member of that caller. C++ does not have a way to interrogate the caller; you would need to pass the caller into the function like void buildTree(OurMap& _mapInstance, GenericValue& doc){ _mapInstance.getValue();}